# My 4 python loops take too long

Tags: python, runtime, nested-loops

This code is taking too long too finish. I already did all I know to make it work and left it running for an hour. 
I am trying to solve this problem:

Let a, b, c, and n be positive integers. If a+b+c = 19*97 and a+n = b-n = c/n compute the value of a.

Here my code:

```
from itertools import *
import gc
gc.disable()
a_list = []
ah = 0
b_num = 0
c_num = 0
number_of_solutions = 0
for a, b, c, n in product(range(1, 19*97), repeat=4):
        if a+b+c == 19*97 and a+n == b-n and b-n == c/n and a+n == c/n:
            a_num = a
            b_num = b
            c_num = c
            a_list.append(a)
            number_of_solutions = number_of_solutions + 1
        else:
            pass

print a_num+b_num+c_num
print a_list
print number_of_solutions
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Your search space size is `(19*97)**4`. That's really, really big. I can think of a few ways to narrow it down. For example, you can vary `a` and `n` from 1 to 19*97, and then calculating `b` and `c` is trivial. There's probably an algebraic solution though

Answer (score 3):

Brute-forcing all possible combinations is inefficient. Instead, do some algebra. Eliminate variables.

```
(a+n) + (b-n) == (c/n) + (c/n)
a+b == 2*c/n
a+b+c == 2*c/n + c == 19*97
c*(2+n) == 19*97*n
```

Since `a+n == c/n` and `a`, `b`, `c`, and `n` are positive integers, `c` is a multiple of `n`, so

```
(2+n) * (c/n) == 19*97
```

`(2+n)` must be 19, 97, or 19*97. You can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.  As @ChrisBarker says, your search space is huge.  There are three main ways to narrow it down a lot.

1. When you've determined a, b is roughly restricted to the range 1 <= b < 19*97-a.
2. When you've determined a and b, c is completely determined by a + b + c = 19*97
3. When you've determined a and b, n is completely determined by a + n = b - n (i.e. n = (b-a)/2)

Here's an edited version of your code that solves this in a few seconds:

```
a_list = []
ah = 0
b_num = 0
c_num = 0
number_of_solutions = 0

for a in range(1, 19*97):
    for b in range(1, 19*97-a):
        c = 19*97 - b - a
        n = (b - a) / 2
        if n > 0 and n*2 == (b-a) and c/n == a+n:
            print "Found a solution! a=%d, b=%d, c=%d, n=%d" % (a, b, c, n)
            a_num = a
            b_num = b
            c_num = c
            a_list.append(a)
            number_of_solutions = number_of_solutions + 1
print
print a_num+b_num+c_num
print a_list
print number_of_solutions
```